# Creating and displaying a simple core-list

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, material-design, core-elements

I cannot get a simple core-list to display its data.

DART FILE

```dart
  import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';


  @CustomTag( 'core-list-demo' )
  class CoreListDemoForm extends PolymerElement
  {

    @observable
    List list;
    @observable bool selectionEnabled = true;

    CoreListDemoForm.created() : super.created();

    void selectionMade( e )
    {
      print( e['detail'].activate );
    }

    void onReady()
    {
      $[ 'kore-list' ].on ['core-activate'].listen( handleListChange );

      list = toObservable(
          [ new Name( 'Fred', 'Tomas'),
            new Name( 'Teddy', 'Clarke' ),
            new Name( 'Paul', 'Taggart' )
          ] );
    }

    handleListChange()
    {
      print ( 'list changed' );
    }

    void selection( e )
    {

    }


  }

  class Name
  {
    @observable String first = '';
    @observable String last = '';

    Name( this.first, this.last );
  }
```

HTML FILE

```dart
        <!DOCTYPE html>

        <link rel='import' href='../../../packages/polymer/polymer.html'>

        <link href = '../../../packages/core_elements/core_list_dart.html' rel = 'import' >

        <polymer-element name = 'core-list-demo'>
          <template>   
            <div class='card'>
                <h3>Core List</h3>
              <hr>
                    <core-list-dart 
                      id="kore-list" 
                      data="{{list}}" 
                      selectionEnabled="{{selectionEnabled}}"
                      selection="{{selection}}"
                      height="10" 
                      on-core-activate =  '{{ selectionMade }}'>
                        <template repeat if = "{{ list }}">
                            <div >{{ model.first }}</div>
                        </template>
              </core-list-dart>

          </div>    
          </template>

          <script type = 'application/dart' src = 'core_list_demo.dart'></script>
        </polymer-element>
```

I simply would like to see the name displayed and the row item data printed when the row is clicked (on-tab).

I have looked some examples but they have not helped.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the fields of your model class observable you not only need the `@observable` annotation but also the `Observable` mixin

```dart
 class Name extends Object with Observable
  {
    @observable String first = '';
    @observable String last = '';

    Name( this.first, this.last );
  }
```

You don't need this for fields in a Polymer element class because `PolymerElement` already includes `Observable`.

You don't need the `repeat` on the `<template>` tag for the list item. `<core-list-dart>` does the reapeating.
I think the main problem is the `if` in the template tag though. This should be enough:

```dart
<template>
  <div >{{ model.first }}</div>
</template>
```

Comment: I made the corrections but still nothing is displayed.

Comment: @ Günter Zöchbauer @Brian Geppert Answered a little hastily before. I see the names displayed now. However the following is a problem |$[ 'kore-list' ].on['core-activate'].listen( handleListChange );| There might be a problem in the handleListChange.

Comment: If the model Name has a third property 'selected', how can I bind the model 'selected' to the 'selected' attribute of the div element in the html file above? In |<div  selected = '{{ selected }}' >selected: {{selected}}</div>| the div text is displayed correctly but the div attribute does not bind to the observable selected property.

Answer (score 0):

I think your main problem is that your `void onReady` should look like:

```dart
@override
void ready() {
  ...
}
```

Your template element inside of `<core-list-dart/>` should look like:

```dart
<template>
  <div>{{ model.first }}</div>
</template>
```

This might due to the copy/paste to StackOverflow, but you shouldn't have any spaces in the middle of your attribute declarations (for example, `rel = 'import'` should be `rel='import'`) and there shouldn't be a space in between `$[ 'kore-list' ].` and `on['core-activate'].listen( handleListChange );`

Comment: read() was problematic too. Please see my comment above. I am not so sure that the spaces should pose a problem. I have been using them without any issues. For me it makes the code more readable. I appreciate the suggestion though.